# PayPal integration with my website(I had read existing posts already)

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

I'm new to coding so pardon me for asking such a dummy question. I'm asking my question in points according to coding I posted.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="user@gmail.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Item Name" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="0.00" />
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!" />
</form>
```

1. This one is for redirecting to PayPal(If I'm right).
2. I didn't understand why we used this.
3. It's for my business PayPal id which I have so no problem with this one.
4. I know it's for Item Name. But my problem is I don't know what to do in here. I already have my custom Cart.aspx page. My question is how to bind selected product name to Item Name field. I mean when I click on buy button, it should automatically binds the product I have selected and so on. Do I have to enter the name as I entered in the Cart table? I'm so confused with what to enter in Item Name field.
5. It's for currency.
6. Same as 4 point.
7. nothing.
8. nothing.
   Please do care to explain I seriously need your guys help.

Comment: This not clear where are you facing problem and which part you dont understand

Comment: I already mentioned clearly that I'm not sure how to integrate Item Name and Price with my website. I mean what I have to enter in there so that it automatically fetches Item name and price from my cart.

Comment: The most confusing word in your question is `this` used like a c# `this` operator everywhere.

Comment: I'm sorry about that I wasn't aware of that but it's not a c# operator. Anyway, can anyone please help me with this thing.

Comment: Edit you question. ask in such a way that other can understand your problem. People out here are ready to help you provided they understand your question.

Comment: It's done, now anyone care to help?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the payment method of above code is called PayPal Standard.

It basically redirect a user it to PayPal website. Then let the user pay at PayPal website.

Unfortunately, you cannot use above code inside ASP.Net page, because of the **form** tag. Instead, you want to post it from code behind.

*The following code collects the user posted data (from textboxes) and redirect the user to PayPal website.*

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string url = TestMode ? 
      "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr" : 
      "https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr";

   var builder = new StringBuilder();
   builder.Append(url);
   builder.AppendFormat("?cmd=_xclick&business={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Email));
   builder.Append("&lc=US&no_note=0&currency_code=USD");
   builder.AppendFormat("&item_name={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ItemName));
   builder.AppendFormat("&invoice={0}", TransactionId);
   builder.AppendFormat("&amount={0}", Amount);
   builder.AppendFormat("&return={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ReturnUrl));
   builder.AppendFormat("&cancel_return={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(CancelUrl));
   builder.AppendFormat("&undefined_quantity={0}", Quantity);
   builder.AppendFormat("&item_number={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ItemNumber));

   Response.Redirect(builder.ToString());
}
```

[HTML Variables for PayPal Payments Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/)

Comment: Thanks this cleared few doubts. But how to bind my selected product and other values with your coding or is it already bind. Please do explain a bit.

Comment: **Email, ItemName, TransactionId, Amount, ReturnUrl, CancelUrl and ItemNumber** are fixed and they are all yours. Only thing a customer chose is **Quantity** (it could be a **DropDownList**). Of course, there are few other information you can collect from the customer (look at the link for details). Test it first by posting a simple one, then add extra field later.

Comment: @Win can you clarify "you cannot use above code inside ASP.Net page, because of the form tag"? As stated, it is not true. Form tags can post wherever you want. If that code is *inside* another form, then what you said is true, but because of nested forms, not ASP.NET. I use multiple forms in ASP.NET all the time.